# Passing parameter values to a PowerShell script

Tags: json, powershell

The following is a **snippet** from my PowerShell script where the values for the parameters `$book` and `$author` are not getting substituted. Please suggest some techniques that I can apply to fix it or share some code that can help me out.

```
$body = @{
version = '1.0'
inactive = 'false'
yml = { "Service1:\n book: $book\n author: $author\n "} | ConvertFrom-Json
} | ConvertTo-Json

$request = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body 
$body -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType

$response = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $request.Content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some weird stuff going on in this line

```
... yml = { "Service1:\n book: $book\n author: $author\n "} | ConvertFrom-Json } | ConvertTo-Json
```

Because it says "do a [script block](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-scriptblock.html) with this body, and try to convert the script block to JSON".

So, if you want to have a JSON string in `yml` field, you have two options.

1. Write the proper JSON string yourself:

   ```
   @{...put the rest of your elements here...; yml = "{Service1:'', book:'$book', author: '$author'}"
   ```
2. Populate a [hashtable](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-hash-tables.html) first and then convert it to JSON string:

   ```
   @{...put the rest of your elements here...; yml = @{Service1=''; book='$book'; author='$author'} } | ConvertTo-Json
   ```

Comment: @vorou...I think you may not have looked at the curly braces carefully.... the ConvertTo-Json is for the outer-most construct and the ConvertFrom-Json is only for that element in that hashtable... Please have another look... thank you for suggesting those 2 options... let me try and I'll let you knkow...

Comment: Please ignore my question as I am no longer seeking solutions... It has been taken care of thru some other technology. Really appreciate the hep though.

Comment: Please ignore my question as I am no longer seeking solutions... It has been taken care of thru some other technology. Really appreciate the hep though.

Comment: @dn_learner glad to hear you made it. Still, if my answer answered the original question, please mark it as an answer.